# Openvpn server client-connect to a specific Openvpn client configuration

Tags: openvpn

Is there a way to specify what OpenVPN Client configurations to execute a client-connect script. For example, here is my directive on the OpenVPN server.conf file:

```
### SMS Notification on OpenVPN Connection
script-security 2
client-connect connect-openvpn-up.sh
client-disconnect connect-openvpn-down.sh
```

It notifies me for every connection however I want to specify only a particular client (i.e. openvpn_client01.conf connection).

I looked at the OpenVPN 2.4 reference manual and saw there was an option to push configuration parameters to clients but did not see anything regarding script execution.

Answer (score 0):

the $common_name variable is available in your client-connect script, and you can test that variable for a specific client certificate common name to perform an action. You can echo out env from within your script to see a list of all the environment variables available in your script.